# Bind a ListBox inside an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

Good Day guys,
I want to create a List of clients and each client has a group of Items he want's to buy, just like a shopping cart.
The method I want to do use to do this is to create a ListBox inside an ItemsControl like this:

```
        <ItemsControl Name="clientList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="46">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="46"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="client" Text="{Binding Client}" Height="45" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,5" FontSize="26"/>
                        <ListBox Name="itemsList" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I do know how to populate the clientList, but the itemsList I just don't know how to Bind it I have List in my code behind but how am I going to access the itemsList from the code behind to bind it with the collection.

This is my code behind:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Load the files in the Isolated Storage
        var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Retrieve the files
        string[] clientlist = appStorage.GetFileNames();

        foreach (string client in clientlist)
        {
            //Populate the clients list
            clients.Add(new Cart { Client = client });

            using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(client, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    //Retrieve the content of the file
                    string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    //Retrieve every item in the file content
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < fileContent.Length)
                    {
                        //Format the file content to the desired format
                        string savedItems = fileContent.Substring(i, 20);
                        savedItems.Replace("-", "  ");


                        //Populate the items ListBox
                        items.Add(new Cart { Items = savedItems });

                        //Move to the next item
                        i += 20;
                    }


                    //Populate clientList
                    clientList.ItemsSource = clients;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Cart is a class that has two string properties Client and Items. The clients are showing in my screen but the items are not showing. so any idea where is the problem?
So any idea where is the problem?

Comment: When and why do you need to get the `itemsList`? (this will help to answer correctly to your question)

Comment: Well why is as I said, is to contain the client's wanted items,(juste like a shopping cart). The client will choose a number of items, they will be added to an ObservableCollection. I want to bind this collection to the ItemSource of the itemsList. the resault will be showing on the screen a list of clients, and for each client the items he chose will be listed under his name.

Answer (score 1):

You've already bound it with the `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`.
So, you just have to add the `Items` property to your `Cart` class.

```
public class Cart
{
    public ObservableCollection<ShoppingItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public Client()
    {
         Items = new ObservableCollection<ShoppingItem>();
    }
}
```

### Update

Given the code you submitted, I figured out where your error comes from:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Load the files in the Isolated Storage
    var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    //Retrieve the files
    string[] clientlist = appStorage.GetFileNames();

    foreach (string client in clientlist)
    {
        Cart cart = new Cart { Client = client };

        //Populate the clients list
        clients.Add(cart);

        using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(client, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                List<string> cartItems = new List<cartItems>();

                //Retrieve the content of the file
                string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

                //Retrieve every item in the file content
                for (int i = 0 ; i < fileContent.Length ; i += 20)
                {
                    //Format the file content to the desired format
                    string savedItems = fileContent.Substring(i, 20);
                    savedItems = savedItems.Replace("-", "  ");  // A string is immutable so Replace does not modify savedItems but returns a new string

                    cartItems.Add(savedItems);
                }

                cart.Items = cartItems;
            }
        }

        //Populate clientList
        clientList.ItemsSource = clients;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it works now, but your code is quite difficulte to understand and contains several mistakes/possible improvements (String.Replace method, while -> for, clients/clientList/clientlist ???).

Comment: Well I've trien to replace the source of clients with the source of items, and the the clientsList showed the items (whitch means the code works), but when I changed back it doesn't work the itemsList is still empty.